# Show / Hide DIV with Javascript from external variable

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I would like to hide or show a DIVs depending on variable coming from a XML file.

```
    <div id="LINK_FAV_1">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link 1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="LINK_FAV_2">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link 2</a>
    </div>
```

I tried that script, but it does not work can you tell me what is wrong please ?

```
<script>
for(i = 1; i <= 2 ; i++)    
document.getElementById('LINK_FAV_'+i).style.display = getXMLValue(xmlData, 'DIV_LINK_FAV_'+i);
</script>
```

XML file is as follow :

```
<response>
<DIV_LINK_FAV_1>'none';</DIV_LINK_FAV_1>
<DIV_LINK_FAV_2>'block';</DIV_LINK_FAV_2>
</response>
```

If necessary, i can change at client side the XML variable answer if current syntax such as : 'none'; or 'block'; is not appropriate.

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: What is your `getXMLValue` function? I would guess it might not be stripping out the semi-colon and quotation marks, and that your XML nodes should instead contain simply `none` and `block` (no quotation marks or semi-colon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon and quotes from the XML values so that they do not form part of the string that you set to the 'display' property of your elements.

```
<response>
<DIV_LINK_FAV_1>none</DIV_LINK_FAV_1>
<DIV_LINK_FAV_2>block</DIV_LINK_FAV_2>
</response>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Without semi-colon it still won't work.  The div is displayed although it should not ...

Comment: Sorry, try removing the quotes too. I have updated my answer.